# How to generate a Accord.Math.Sparse<double> element in C#?

Tags: c#, sparse-matrix, accord.net, dot-product

I am trying to implement in C# the dot product, to do so, I am using Accord.Math and its method Dot as follows:

```
using Accord.Math;

namespace VectorOperations
{
    class DotProduct
    {
        private static double CalculateDotProduct(Sparse<double> Vector1, Sparse<double> Vector2)
        {
            double DotProduct = Vector.Dot(Vector1, Vector2);
            return DotProduct;
        }
    }
}
```

However I am not able to create an example where I can test if it is working correctly fine because I don't know how to create a variable of type `Sparse<double>`. How could I create one as an example? Ideally, I would like to have:

```
Sparse<double> Vector1 = new Sparse<double>();
Sparse<double> Vector2 = new Sparse<double>();

// Vector1 = [1, 2, 3];
// Vector2 = [1, 2, 3];
```

So I can call `this.CalculateDotProduct(Vector1, Vector2)` and check if it works correctly.

If you know any other method to compute the dotproduct with vectors of type `List<double>` are welcome too.

Comment: There is no `Sparse[T]` class in .NET. Something that might be functionally simmilar is `Lazy[T]` for lazy initialisation. `new Sparse<double>()` seems incomplete, as there is no code attached to deal with how to Initialize the value when it is called.

Comment: ``Sparse[T]`` is a data type used in the Accord library.

Comment: A sparse vector you need three points for each value : 1) X  2) Y 3) Value.  A Sparse matrix does not save every x and y value.  So you can use any object that has these three values like a Tuple of create you own class with properties x, y, and value.

Comment: @Marisa: It is still not clear to me what that class does. My best guess is a "Lazy Initilisation Array"? A array where eachy value is lazily initialized.

Comment: This is just a guess, but could it be as simple as `new Sparse<double>() { 1, 2, 3 }` or `Vector1.Add(1); Vector1.Add(2); Vector1.Add(3)`?

Comment: @Christopher [`Sparse<T>`](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Math_Sparse_1.htm) is a sparse vector, i.e. a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @Stijn I already tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you get an error? Does it not compile? Please clarify how "it doesn't work".

Comment: It says that Sparse<T> doesn't contain a definition for add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [unit tests](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Unit%20Tests/Accord.Tests.Core/SparseTest.cs) show a couple of ways to create and fill an instance:

```
var s = new Sparse<double>();
s[0] = 1;
s[99] = 99;
s[10] = 42;

v = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6 };
d = Sparse.FromDense(v);
```

Another way is using the [`Sparse(int[] indices, T[] values)`](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Sparse_1__ctor_2.htm) constructor:

```
Sparse<double> Vector1 = new Sparse<double>(new[] { 0, 1, 2 }, new[]  { 1, 2, 3 });
```